# Angularjs Routing in Windws 8 Store Apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-store-apps

I am new to windows store app development. Any how manage to get worked angularjs inside Windows 8 store app by editing angular js library. But Could not understand how to use angulerjs routing inside store app.

Can anyone explain how to use angular js routing in side Windows Store app or give an example to how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a universal app and I'm using angularjs.

It is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/views/default.html',
            controller: 'default'
        }).
        when('/customers', {
            templateUrl: '/views/customers.html',
            controller: 'customers'
        }).
        when('/products/:param', {
            templateUrl: '/views/products.html',
            controller: 'products'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

I have the below code for opening customers screen.

```
$scope.openCustomers = function () {
    $location.path('/customers');
}
```

I have the below code for opening products screen.

```
$scope.openProducts  = function () {
    $location.path('/products/123');
}
```

It is my customers controller code

```
app.controller('customers', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

});
```

It is my products controller code

```
app.controller('products', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope,$routeParams) {
    $scope.param= $routeParams.param;
});
```

Comment: Could you use this in windows store app ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using universal app project with javascript. You can get more detail here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/08/building-windows-phone-8-1-apps-in-html.aspx